# Writing a Parquet.Net file using RLE_DICTIONARY encoding

Tags: c#, parquet, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1, parquet.net

The `Parquet.Net` specification says I can read and write in `RLE_DICTIONARY` encoding. I am trying to read the docs of `Parquet.Net` and the github repo code, but how do I write my DataTable to use this encoding?

The demo I am basing this off of is found here:

[Stack Overflow Parquet Size Discrepancy Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64486205/parquet-net-is-generating-huge-parquet-files-in-comparison-with-pyarrow)

Answer (score -1):

I'm finding this answer either, I just found an answer  like this:
if you are using spark  just write DataFrame  with

```
df.write
.option("parquet.enable.dictionary",true) //true is RLE_DICTIONARY and false plain (maybe)
.parquet(yourPath)
```

Comment: Spark is not Dotnet Core